# How To Convert MP4 Video File into FLV Format Using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, mp4

i have to Convert MP4 Video File into FLV Format Using FFMPEG which i received from different mobile device. i found most of the stuff to convert flv video into mp4 and all.

can any body help me out to convert mp4 format into flv using FFMPEG. i am using windows 7 64bit machine.

Comment: If i understand correctly you need to do this within an application right? What language are you programming in?
If you only need to convert video, i recommend to use S.U.P.E.R.
http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html

Comment: And I suggest you to go ask this question on superuser.com since it's not programming related.

Comment: @Thomas Yes i want to convert video file using webservice. i am using vb.net2005.

Comment: @karlphillip I want to convert video using vb.net and ffmpeg.

Comment: It's important to state that in the question.

Answer (score 70):

I'm late, but if this can help somebody, it's time well spent.

If I understand correctly, you want to convert MP4 to FLV using FFMPEG. Here are two command lines to help you do that; I'm currently using them myself (you can adjust them to your needs too) :

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 destinationfile.flv
```

and if the first one doesn't work :

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 destinationfile.flv
```

Please note that `-crf XX` is the quality of the video you will create. It's between 0 and 51 (but between 17 and 23 is a reasonable range and the lower the number is, the better quality the video is going to be).

The `-ar 22050` is for adjusting the audio sample range (audio quality). You can choose 11025, 22050 or 44100.

I suggest you read this [Tutorial for FFMPEG](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) . It's really complete and has many useful tips.

Hope this will help you or somebody in the same situation.

Comment: This is great and complete answer - it should be accepted - it definitely helped me as I was looking for exactly the same, to convert mp4 to flv using ffmpeg.

Comment: as a side note: i was ready to go with `choco install ffmpeg` - "Adobe Media Encoder" does not support FLV anymore, so this did it for me

Comment: i ended up with `ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -strict experimental -vcodec "flv1" -qscale "4" -an converted.flv` to have a **Adobe Animate CC** import compatible file with good quality and no sound (`-an` removes the sound, use `-ar 22050` otherwise).. all done on windows.